# How to query a table to get a sequence or chain of records?

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table like below

[image: TaskDel3gation]

A user can assign tasks to other user. Other user in turn can assign his/her task to another user and so on.

User assigning tasks will be identified by TASK_ASSIGN_USERID, and user receiving the task will be identified by TASK_RCV_USERID.

Users can assign tasks to others for a specific period of time identified by EFFECTIVE_DATE and EXPIRATION_DATE.

A user cannot assign task to other user if the other user already has a task in the specified duration.

Tasks/records which are filling behind the current date are treated as inactive/completed tasks.

I want to query the table to get the current active tasks given a TASK_ASSIGN_USERID. The query should return the record for the requested TASK_ASSIGN_USERID, a record another if the  TASK_RCV_USERID assigned the task to someone else. In turn if the TASK_RCV_USERID assigned to another user it should return me another record and so on.

Sample

> TASK_ASSIGN_USERID    TASK_RCV_USERID
>
> A       B
>
> B       C
>
> C       D
>
> D       E
>
> ....
>
> ....

I am using db2 database. Can anyone please help me? Currently I am using a for loop in my code to retrieve all records.

If this cannot be done using SQL then I would like to use pl/SQL.

Can anyone please help me?

Updated:

> TASK_ASSIGN_USERID | TASK_RCV_USER_ID | EFFECTIVE_DATE | EXPIRATION_DATE
>
> A                  | B                | 10-11-2016     | 17-11-2016
>
> B                  | C                | 11-11-2016     | 16-11-2016
>
> A                  | B                | 12-11-2016     | 20-11-2016
>
> B                  | C                | 15-11-2016     | 18-11-2016
>
> C                  | D                | 15-11-2016     | 18-11-2016

Should give me below, when TASK_ASSIGN_USERID = A

> TASK_ASSIGN_USERID | TASK_RCV_USER_ID | EFFECTIVE_DATE | EXPIRATION_DATE
>
> A                  | B                | 12-11-2016     | 20-11-2016
>
> B                  | C                | 15-11-2016     | 18-11-2016
>
> C                  | D                | 15-11-2016     | 18-11-2016

Should give me below, when TASK_ASSIGN_USERID = B

> TASK_ASSIGN_USERID | TASK_RCV_USER_ID | EFFECTIVE_DATE | EXPIRATION_DATE
>
> B                  | C                | 15-11-2016     | 18-11-2016
>
> C                  | D                | 15-11-2016     | 18-11-2016

Should give me below, when TASK_ASSIGN_USERID = C

> TASK_ASSIGN_USERID | TASK_RCV_USER_ID | EFFECTIVE_DATE | EXPIRATION_DATE
>
> C                  | D                | 15-11-2016     | 18-11-2016

Comment: First, correct your tagging. PLSQL is ORACLE's, not DB2.

Comment: Updated. But i see some documentation in IBM for plsql.

Comment: PL SQL is used by DB2 too ^^ http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053607.html

Comment: I don't know why this question deserves a down vote. I did my homework before posting the question.

Comment: i agree... May be can you give an example data before/data after for better illustration of you want

Comment: What version of DB2 are you running, and on which platform?

Comment: @Esperento57 updated my post

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select TASK_ASSIGN_USERID,TASK_RCV_USER_ID, max( EFFECTIVE_DATE) as  EFFECTIVE_DATE, max (EXPIRATION_DATE) as EXPIRATION_DATE
from youtable
group by TASK_ASSIGN_USERID,TASK_RCV_USER_ID
```

Comment: i need it for the specified user id. updated my post again.